# Contradicting Results of a Truss Structure

Tags: structural-analysis

[image]

[image]

I saw this analysis online but I have noticed contradicting values from this method of analysis. The drawing of the simply supported beam comes from the crane structure above. All we desire is the reaction forces as well as the external forces being experienced at each of the three points which represent the joints of part of the truss. The person has placed $150N$ acting in the middle of the beam creating a moment of $22500 Nmm$ and creating reactions of $75N$ at each support.

But I was told on one of my previous questions that this is innorect due to it being part of a truss and not just a beam. Is the correct way to split up the $150N$ into $50N$ acting upon points $P_1$ $P_2$ and $P_3$ which would result in a total moment of $30000 Nmm$ and reactions of $100N$ on the right end and $50N$ on the left end? Which method is correct in this situation?

Comment: is the concentrated load of 150 N the result of a distributed load over 300 mm?

Comment: Yes it is the result of a distributed load over 300 mm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't know which question you are referring to but) IMHO -if you take the usual assumption (i.e. non deformable structure)- the correct way would be the following :

[image]

---

**Note that** in terms of moment this will have the same effect, however, the loads on the truss's rods will be different than if you used a different  scheme.

So, for the loads on the support either the concentrated load or the distributed load or the scheme I am proposing should have no difference.

---

The whole concept behind this, is the resultant of parallel forces (well actually the opposite). I.e.: if you have two or more parallel forces then which is the resultant force that can substitute those forces.

Essentially for **each segment** you have:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Original | [image] |  |
| Splitting UDL to each side | [image] |  |
| Concentrated Load | [image] |  |

So if you put all segment next to each other

[image]

which results to the first image above

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a way to justify/ prove that for the given scenario that this is the correct way to convert the UDL to points loads. If this were just a beam with no truss attached to it we would use the $150N$ acting in the middle for our calculations wouldn't we? So why is it different when the beam is part of a truss?

Comment: I've updated the answer. However, I am only answering on how to break the load to 25, 50,50 and 25. I have not yet understood what you mean by "If this were just a beam with no truss attached to it we would use the 150N acting in the middle for our calculations wouldn't we?".  Beams and the rods of a truss may seem similar but they behave (most of the time) in different ways. The essence is that **rods** transfer only axial load, while **beams** transfer axial, shear and bending forces. However, unless there is a concrete example I can't really help you.

Comment: Well I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIva-QRumpU involving a truss with a UDL. But in this video the person has placed $1000N$ in the middle of the UDL span. According to your diagrams should it have been $500N$ at each end of the member? If that were the case then at point B, the reaction would be $500N$ acting up but there would still be $500N$ acting down but then for equilibrium $F_2$ would need to have no vertical component?

Comment: Also I'm not really understanding how you derived that the forces are 25, 50, 50 and 25. By looking at each segment there is a total of $50N$ acting over the segment or $25N$ per $50$ mm as you have split the UDL into two sections I am assuming from the diagram. But how does this result in $25N$ acting on each end of the segment?

Comment: On a truss rod you can only place forces on the edges  of the rod (aka nodes). I will try to explain it intuitively (without using equations of equilibrium). Since you have a total load of 50 N, and you need to split it at two, then 25 goes to one end, and 25 on the other.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are there any resources to learn more about this? I think for me mathematical proof makes more sense.

Comment: regarding the video (youtube.com/watch?v=VIva-QRumpU) at 2:00 minutes it says that there are number of ways to go about it and obtain the same solution. And then at about 4:30 minutes it explains that when you separate the rod and examine it, you can substitute the load with a single concentrated load. (SIDENOTE:  For this simple structure -- which is not really a truss--  this works also). If you tried with the scheme I suggested - splitting the loads to 500 at each end of the node you would still get the same result ( see around 6:00).

Comment: BTW, like the guy states at 6:07 its pretty obvious that when there is a UDL on a rod of 1000 N then the load is split to 500N and 500N which how I obtained the 25N. If even intuitively that does not make sense, and you need the math, then my advice is to follow a proper statics course.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. I see that if we use your scheme then the reactants $A_y$ and $B_y$  would be the same at $500N$. But if we consider joint B, We have $500N$ acting down because we split up the UDL and then we also have $500N$ acting up from the resultant which gives different member forces than the video's method as now for equilibrium $F_2$ is required to have no vertical component. What am I missing here?

Comment: Νο, because the $B_y$ is the reaction force on B. You need to have a 500N downwards force at B because that is the external excitation.

Comment: Ah ok. So the reaction force at $B$ tells you that at that point in order for equilibrium there must be a force of $500N$ which is exterted by the members? In my class when solving regular truss problems with point loads we find the reactions at each support. Then when it comes to solving for the member forces and we start from one of the supports we take into account the reaction force as one of the forces which is acting on the joint. But in the video we aren't treating $B_y$ as a force which is acting on the joint. Is this becuase $B$ is not a support it is just a joint?

Comment: My apologies, but I don't think I can help you further in this. You seem to be jumping from one example to the other (you started with the question problem and at the same time you were referencing another question, then there was the video problem and now you are referencing yet another problem), which is not optimal for this forum. Since you seem to be already taking a class its best to ask your instructor.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

For reactions' concern, the UDL, the point loads, and the concentrated load (Pe) are all **equivalent**.

Let's check the forces at the joint "K":

- Fk = 50 N/100 mm * 300 mm = 150 N (using UDL)
- Fk = 2*25 N + 4*25 N = 150 N (using Joint loads)
- Fk = 150 N (Concentrated load)
- Mk = 50 N/100 mm * 300 mm * 150 mm = 22500 N-mm (using UDL)
- Mk = 25*(0) + 50*100 + 50*200 +25*300 = 22500 N-mm (using Joint loads)
- Mk = 150*150 = 22500 N-m (using Concentrated load)

**Conclusion** - the equivalent loads will produce identical forces/reactions at any point of the truss. However, as mentioned previously, the internal forces on the truss members will be different. Now for the beam, note the differences in bending and shear forces on the diagrams below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answers given with the exception that the moment of the concentrated load of 150N should not be applied at a distance of 150mm. it should be broken into two loads of 75N and each applied respectively at 100mm and 200mm.

As far as the stress in members we also should work the horizontal component of the cable tension as an axial force to all three horizontal members.

So the members are under combined moment and normal stresses.